# Can't compare variable

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to check if a variable from my spinner is a certain string and it says that the variable i am trying to check is a declared variable. I believe it is because i haven't declared the variable as global as i declared it in this code. The variable is "selectedItem" and this code is for checking what item was clicked and sets it to a textview i also need changed.

```
var choice = findViewById<View>(R.id.textView_choice) as TextView
        spinner_1?.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

            }

            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                var selectedItem = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()

                choice.setText(selectedItem)


            }

        }
```

Here is where i compare it:

```
if (selectedItem == "Forest") {
            val img = findViewById<View>(R.id.ImageView_pl1) as ImageView
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.forest)
        }
```

What did i do wrong?

Comment: Have you log the selectedItem value in log cat?What value is coming there?

Comment: I don't know what is log?@GowthamKK

Comment: You can use the `Log.d` method (that's Debug level, there are others) to print a value to your logs, and view it in the *Logcat* tab - it's important so you should learn how to do it! Where exactly is this comparison code in the second bit? If it's not inside `onItemSelected` then it can't see the `selectedItem` variable you declared in there. You haven't posted enough code for us to tell what's going on though

Comment: It is in the second part of the code at the beginning "if (selectedItem == "Forest")"@cactustictacs

Comment: @cactustictacs do i need to declare it as a global variable in that case? If so, how do i do that?

Comment: I'm asking where that second code block *is* in relation to the first. Is it in another method in the same class? Is it in another class entirely? Without knowing how those code blocks relate to each other, we can't tell you how to fix it. Generally speaking, either put the second block inside `onItemSelected` i.e. where the `selectedItem` variable *is*; or put the second block inside a function with an `item` parameter and compare to *that*, and make `onItemSelected` call that function passing `selectedItem` in. I don't want to give advice about top-level variables without knowing what's up

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the comparison function where the strings are compared should be called from inside of

```
override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
            var selectedItem = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()

            choice.setText(selectedItem)


        }
```

I don't see any comparison function call or logic inside the function onItemSelected block.